# Blurred on animated wings

Tags: blur

[image]I would like to know how to add a blur only to a moving element, like my wings here:

https://www.facebook.com/100070162777267/videos/5749069868505641/

Have a nice day and thank you

---

[image]

[image]

Thank you, I had already done it Motion Blur in Renders Proprietie and forgot Rolling Shutter. I tried it again with Rolling Shutter at TopBottom, but it still doesn't work. I then tried the Vector Blur [recommended her](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20motion%20blur&oq=blender%20motion%20blur&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyCQgAEEUYORiABDIHCAEQABiABDIICAIQABgWGB4yCAgDEAAYFhgeMggIBBAAGBYYHjIICAUQABgWGB4yCggGEAAYDxgWGB4yCAgHEAAYFhgeMggICBAAGBYYHjIICAkQABgWGB7SAQkxNjA3MWowajeoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:636008aa,vid:GK7KDT5750E,st:0)e (the last step). Without success

I have Blender 3.3.1

Comment: Hello, in the Render panel, have you tried to activate Motion Blur?

Comment: Hello, please avoid posting external links and keep examples of your work in the body of the text. :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.